# sql insert PROBLEM

Tags: sql, insert

I want to get data from one table and transfer it to another like-for-like table on another pc.

Is there a sql command where i can do an "insert into table....."
( but knowing the current values)

Better explaination:

Imagine you have 2 PC's. Both on separate servers. I want to update the information from a table in PC 1 into PC 2. How?

Comment: what do you mean with "but knowing tha current values"?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the database product.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C FROM OtherTable
```

**EDIT**: Many database servers allow you to connect to a different server and use its data.
Your question cannot be answered without more detail.

In SQL Server, you can [set up a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), then write `SELECT A, B, C FROM Server2.Database.Schema.OtherTable`.

Comment: Not quite because there data should come from a different pc

Comment: -1 Question specifically asked about source and destination tables existing on different PCs i.e. different MySQL instances.

Comment: @Adrian: When I gave this answer, the question didn't say that. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5221141/revisions

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Just change it to reference the server names.

Comment: @Nathan: Which DB servers do that?

Comment: SQL Server, assuming you've set them up as linked servers.

Comment: @SLaks The first revision says "transfer it to another like-for-like table on another pc".